# Can SNS filter be applied at same time as subscription?

Tags: amazon-sns

Suppose an AWS SNS topic. Messages on this topic have the MessageAttribute "IsTestMessage" of type String.

Using the AWS console, I add a new email subscriber. They receive a confirmation email. On confirming, they would receive all messages on this topic, including test messages. This is not intended.

I would like to have a filter applied prior to their confirmation, permitting me to say `IsTestMessage: "false"` for example.

Can I apply the filter at the time of subscription creation to avoid these incorrect deliveries? There does not appear to be a way in the console to do so, but I'm open to using CLI, SDK, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon SNS [Subscribe](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_Subscribe.html) API call has a field called `Attributes`:

> Assigns attributes to the subscription as a map of key-value pairs. You can assign any attribute that is supported by the `SetSubscriptionAttributes` action.

The [SetSubscriptionAttributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetSubscriptionAttributes.html) API call can accept a `FilterPolicy` as per [Filtering Messages with Amazon SNS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html).

That should meet your requirements.

Comment: This does not work for me. Using CLI on powershell. If I omit the "attributes", it creates the subscription. If I include `--attributes FilterPolicy='{ \"IsTestMessage\": [ \"false\" ] }'` , I get "Access Denied" with no further information.

Comment: I can't get the correct syntax to call `Subscribe` with `--attributes FilterPolicy`. Can you supply the full command you used?

Comment: Full command in powershell: `aws sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:99999999:MyTopic --protocol email --notification-endpoint myemail@mydomain.com --attributes FilterPolicy='{ \"IsTestMessage\": [ \"false\" ] }'`  obviously using fake values

Comment: When I try that command, I get: `Error parsing parameter '--attributes': Expected: '=', received: '"' for input:
FilterPolicy={ "IsTestMessage": [ "false" ] }`

Answer (score 0):

Going through the CLI, I kept hitting the same error as @John Rotenstein: `Error parsing parameter '--attributes': Expected: '=', received: '"'`

No matter what I tried, it wasn't taking it, so I can only assume that part of the sdk is borked.

A full bash example of creating an SNS topic, SQS queue, and adding a subscription:

```
# some params - SNS_ENDPOINT and SQS_ENDPOINT are for localstack - you probably don't need them
# in production
SQS_ENDPOINT="${SQS_ENDPOINT:-http://localhost:4566}"
SNS_ENDPOINT="${SNS_ENDPOINT:-http://localhost:4575}"
REGION=eu-west-1

# Create an SNS topic, "my-topic" and extract the ARN
MY_TOPIC_ARN=$(aws sns create-topic --name "my-topic" --endpoint-url=$SNS_ENDPOINT --region=$REGION --query TopicArn --output text)

# Create a SQS queue that will get messages from the SNS topic - extract the url
MY_QUEUE_URL=$(aws sqs create-queue --queue-name "my-queue" --endpoint-url=$SQS_ENDPOINT --region=$REGION --query QueueUrl --output text)

# Get the queue arn
MY_QUEUE_ARN=$(aws sqs get-queue-attributes --queue-url "$MY_QUEUE_URL" --endpoint-url=$SQS_ENDPOINT --attribute-names QueueArn --query Attributes --output text)

# Subscribe our sqs queue to our sns topic - extract the subscription arn
MY_SUBSCRIPTION_ARN=$(aws sns subscribe --topic-arn $MY_TOPIC_ARN --protocol sqs --notification-endpoint $MY_QUEUE_ARN --endpoint-url=$SNS_ENDPOINT --region=$REGION --attributes RawMessageDelivery=true --query SubscriptionArn --output text)

# Add a filter policy
aws sns set-subscription-attributes --subscription-arn $MY_SUBSCRIPTION_ARN --attribute-name FilterPolicy --attribute-value "{\"someKey\":[\"someValue\"]}" --endpoint-url=$SQS_ENDPOINT --region=$REGION
```

**Note:** This doesn't deal with setting up a dead-letter queue (one for the subscription itself, and one for the SQS queue, depending on what you're doing with it), nor the policy that you'll need to allow SNS to send messages to SQS etc

**Cloud Formation**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.cloudformation.html gives an example of creating a topic with a subscription at the same time:

```
"Resources": {
    "MySNSTopic": {
      "Type": "AWS::SNS::Topic",
      "Properties": {
        "Subscription": [{
            "Endpoint": {
              "Fn::GetAtt": ["MyQueue1", "Arn"]
            },
            "Protocol": "sqs"
          }]
      }
    },
    ...
}
```

I haven't tried that one though, so I can't speak to it

**Serverless**

You can also create them separately through Serverless:

```
  Resources: 
    MyTopic:
      Type: "AWS::SNS::Topic"
      Properties:
        TopicName: ${self:custom.myTopicName}

    MyTopicQueue:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${self:custom.myTopicQueueName}
        VisibilityTimeout: 120
        RedrivePolicy: 
          maxReceiveCount: 3
          deadLetterTargetArn:
            Fn::GetAtt: 
              - MyTopicQueueDeadLetter
              - Arn
    MyTopicQueueDeadLetter:
      Type: "AWS::SQS::Queue"
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${self:custom.myTopicDeadQueueName}

    # Policy to allow SNS to post to SQS
    MyTopicQueuePolicy:
      Type: AWS::SQS::QueuePolicy
      Properties:
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service: sns.amazonaws.com
            Resource: 
              - !GetAtt
                - MyTopicQueue
                - Arn
              - !GetAtt
                - MyTopicQueueDeadLetter
                - Arn
            Action: 
              - sqs:*
            Condition:
              ArnEquals:
                aws:SourceArn: !Ref MyTopic
        Queues:
          - Ref: MyTopicQueue
          - Ref: MyTopicQueueDeadLetter

    # Create the subscription for the SNS to SQS queue
    MyTopicSnsToSqsSubscription:
      Type: "AWS::SNS::Subscription"
      Properties:
        TopicArn: !Ref MyTopic
        Endpoint: !GetAtt
          - MyTopicQueue
          - Arn
        Protocol: sqs
        RawMessageDelivery: 'true'
        FilterPolicy:
          type:
            - 'playerLost'
        RedrivePolicy:
          deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt
            - MyTopicQueueDeadLetter
            - Arn
```

I'm still not 100% sure on the policy though, as in the AWS Console, when I look at the subscription, it still says that it doesn't have permission to post to the dead letter queue (here I'm using the same dead letter queue for the subscription and the SQS main queue), so I'm obviously missing something.

Similar to CloudFormation, you can probably declare the subscription directly when declaring the topic, but I haven't tried that.

Should be enough to get you started